# Is there any Cloud backend service for Python kivy framework

Tags: python, cloud, kivy

I am doing research in Python Kivy framework and i found it great for developing apps for cross-platform. But in my app i want to integrate Cloud Backend Service such as Parse. So if anybody come across then please share with us.

Thanks,

Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer on behalf of my research that is 
1.Parse provide a [REST API](http://www.parse.com/docs/rest).
2. someone has written a [Python client](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy).

These are two alternative options which could help for creating a cloud backend with Python based Apps.